# JQuery Mobile - constant url with native back button support

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on a JQM app that has multiple pages, most of which can be automatically generated based on the data they need to display.

I'm using ajax calls to pull-in the json and moustache to generate the html. So far so good.

I wanted to avoid having the url change with every transition because not only does this interfere with the notion of an "app", but it also causes not a small amount of havoc should the user refresh a "sub" page.

So I handle all the page transitions directly with $.mobile.changePage, which allows me to set changeHash to false.

The problem is that when the user hits the browser back button they are taken out of the app.

Is there a way to keep a constant url in the browser bar and still have native back button support?